# How to omit the corrupt value in a program?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I've such errors:

> Coordinate .. is not a floating-point number

and can't correctly fix it.

**The problem occures when `x==Log[2]`**

The program works correctly for a function `1 - t *y` , but not for `y*y*Exp[t] - 2*y` through this problem.

This is a solution for this diff. equation:

[image]

I will be really happy if you tell me why and how to fix this problem.

```
    ABM[a0_, b0_, \[Alpha]_, m0_] := 
  Module[{a = a0, b = b0, F, j, k, m = m0, p}, 
       h = (b - a)/m; T = Table[a, {m + 1}]; 
   Y = Table[\[Alpha], {m + 1}]; 
        For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, Subscript[k, 1] = h*f[T[[j]], Y[[j]]]; 

    Subscript[k, 2] = h*f[T[[j]] + h/2, Y[[j]] + Subscript[k, 1]/2]; 

    Subscript[k, 3] = h*f[T[[j]] + h/2, Y[[j]] + Subscript[k, 2]/2]; 

    Subscript[k, 4] = h*f[T[[j]] + h, Y[[j]] + Subscript[k, 3]]; 

    Y[[j + 1]] = Y[[j]] + (1/6)*(Subscript[k, 1] + 2*Subscript[k, 2] + 
                    2*Subscript[k, 3] + Subscript[k, 4]); 
    T[[j + 1]] = a + h*j; ]; 
        Subscript[F, 0] = f[T[[1]], Y[[1]]]; Subscript[F, 1] = 
          f[T[[2]], Y[[2]]]; Subscript[F, 2] = f[T[[3]], Y[[3]]]; 
        Subscript[F, 3] = f[T[[4]], Y[[4]]]; For[j = 4, j <= m, j++, 

    p = Y[[j]] + (h/24)*(-9*Subscript[F, 0] + 37*Subscript[F, 1] - 
                    59*Subscript[F, 2] + 55*Subscript[F, 3]); 
           T[[j + 1]] = a + h*j; 
    p = Y[[j]] + (h/24)*(Subscript[F, 1] - 
                    5*Subscript[F, 2] + 19*Subscript[F, 3] + 
         9*f[T[[j + 1]], p]); 
           Y[[j + 1]] = p; Subscript[F, 0] = Subscript[F, 1]; 
           Subscript[F, 1] = Subscript[F, 2]; Subscript[F, 2] = 
             Subscript[F, 3]; 
    Subscript[F, 3] = f[T[[j + 1]], Y[[j + 1]]]; ]; 
        Return[Transpose[{T, Y}]]]; 
f[t_, y_] = y*y*Exp[t] - 2*y; 
Print["Find numerical solutions to the D.E."]; 
Print["y' = ", f[t, y]]; 
n = 25; 
pts1 = ABM[0, 8, 2., n]; 
Y1 = Y; 
Needs["Graphics`Colors`"]; 
graph1 = ListPlot[pts1, PlotJoined -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]; 
Print["The Adams-Bashforth-Moulton solution for  y' = ", f[t, y]]; 
Print["Using  n = ", n + 1, "  points."]; 
Print[pts1]; 
Print[""]; 
Print["The final value is  y(5) = ", Subscript[y, n + 1], " = ", 
     Y[[n + 1]]];
```

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  Your code is sound, and the results it gives seems to me to match what I get from `NDSolve`, but the initial condition you have leads to the function blowing up, giving the output "The final value is  y(5) = y_26 = 2.8359*10^143856912789595".  If you change the initial condition to `y[0] = 1.` then it does not diverge

Comment: Found the source of the code above, [here](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/NumericalUndergradMod.html).  It could probably be rewritten for recent versions of *Mathematica*, but it works as written if given good initial conditions.

Comment: One would really hope people would mention where they obtained code in their question if it's not of their own devising. In any case, the default LSODA method of `NDSolve[]` uses a modification of Adams-Bashforth-Moulton internally.

Comment: @JasonB, unfortunately, I've got a condition exactly `y[0]=2`. I use Mathematica-5

Comment: @Julka, for that particular differential equation, with the initial condition you have, the result diverges **very** quickly.

Comment: @J.M. It doesn't work `NDSolve[y'[x] == y[x]*y[x]*Exp[x] - 2*y[x], y[0] == 2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @JasonB, But the solution exists (I added it to post)

Comment: And if I output the points in solution I have:
`{
 {2},
 {-1.0243317499320528},
 {-0.05022596935066152},
 {-0.005505732959388324},
 {-0.0006964366189663772},
 {-0.00009204018326443983},
 {-0.000012349648138839606},
 {-1.6661*10^-6},
 {-2.25221*10^-7},
 {-3.04675*10^-8},
 {-4.12268*10^-9}
}`

Comment: @Julka, so then how would the Adams method handle the situation where there is a singularity at $\ln 2$?  At that point the derivative goes to infinity

Comment: @JasonB, maybe need add any condition?

Comment: @J.M. is more the expert there, he may be able to give pointers on how to solve a differential equation numerically over a region in which the solution has a singularity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38387/discussion-between-julka-and-jasonb).

Comment: Adams and RK methods really aren't suitable for DEs with singular solutions, since they locally use polynomial approximations and no polynomial ever had a pole. There are special methods, but none of these are built into `NDSolve[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is singular and cannot be fixed with Adams's method (see also J.M.'s comment). You can solve it with `DSolve`.

```
nsol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]*y[x]*Exp[x] - 2*y[x], y[0] == 2}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> At x == 0.6931469688260267`, step size is effectively zero; \
>   singularity or stiff system suspected.

```
{x1, x2} = nsol["Domain"][[1]]
(* {0., 0.693147} *)

Plot[nsol[x], {x, x1, x2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^2*Exp[x] - 2 y[x], y[0] == 2}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But I also need a table with points x,y   ;((

Comment: @Julka With pleasure I also fulfil this wish. `Table[{x, sol[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}]`